# trouble with basis in $\Bbb R^5 $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose
$$W = \{(x_1,x_2,...,x_5) \in \Bbb R^5 \mid x_1= 3x_2+x_3,x_2=x_5,x_4=2x_3  \}.$$
How can I find a basis for this space??

Comment: Notice that if you know $x_2,x_3$ then you know all of $x$.

Comment: $x_i$ are vector just simple numbers

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make the basic with $x_2$ and $x_3$ so make $x_1 x_4 $and $ x_5$ with $x_2$ and $x_3$

Answer (score 4):

First, note that all the coordinates are uniquely and completely determined once you know $\;x_5,x_4\;$ , which points towards $\;\dim W=2\;$ , and then *choose*

$$x_4=2\;,\;x_5=0\implies x_3=1\;,\;x_2=0\;,\;x_1=3\cdot 0+1=1\implies \text{ first vector}\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\\2\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Now try to do the above again with $\;x_4=0\,,\,x_5=1\,$ and find the other vector needed for your basis...

Answer (score 2):

Note that the following are equivalent:

$$\vec x\in W\\\vec x=(3x_2+x_3,x_2,x_3,2x_3,x_2)\\\vec x=(3x_2,x_2,0,0,x_2)+(x_3,0,x_3,2x_3,0)\\\vec x=x_2(3,1,0,0,1)+x_3(1,0,1,2,0)$$

Hence, $$\{(3,1,0,0,1),(1,0,1,2,0)\}$$ is a spanning set for $W$, and is readily confirmed to be a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Dimension of $W$ is two. Thus basis can be easily constructed.